# invoke method of another class from widget class

Tags: android, android-widget

```
public class MainActivity extends AppWidgetProvider{
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for(int i=0; i<appWidgetIds.length; i++){
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyLockScreenActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,intent, 0);
        Log.e("in main","onclick");
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.activity_main);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pending);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId,views);
        Toast.makeText(context, "widget added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

this is my code for a widget. instead of calling the another activity, i want to call method from a normal java class.

Comment: What's stopping you? Have you tried it?

Comment: i want to invoke a method of mylock class on the onclick of the button with id button. i dont want to invoke intent to the class. how can i do that?

Comment: You want to call a method of an activity class that isn't currently active? Sounds like a bad idea. Either use an intent to start the activity or move that method to a class that isn't an activity.

Comment: yeah thats what i want to do. invoke the method of a class which is not activity. thatsy i had written normal java class in my question

Comment: So put your method in an appropriate (not activity) class and call it. I don't understand what difficulty you're having with that, can you explain the problem?

Comment: how to implement the onclick listener on the button. is the code i had written is enough? can u plz give me an example to do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94110/discussion-between-sammalik-and-nasch).

Comment: I'm not familiar with widgets specifically but generally you call `findViewById` to get a reference to a view object and then call `setOnClickListener` and pass an anonymous class. In the chick listener call the method you need to call.

Comment: no we cannot make reference of a button by findviewbyid in widget class